# How to get SUM of the Time field in java from Access Database

Tags: java, date, ms-access, time, sum

I have a table called as Break in my access database. However, I need to find the SUM of the field "breakstart" in the same format as it is there in access database. for e.g. in (hh:mm:ss) format.

```
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MominDB","","");
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                rs=stmt.executeQuery("select SUM(totalbreak) AS SUM_HOURS from Break ");
                String s1=null;
                while(rs.next())
                {
                System.out.println(rs);

                 s1=rs.getString("SUM_HOURS");

                }
                System.out.println(s1);
```

It is giving me output as 2.66203703703704E-4. Any help would be appreciated.

Even the below code did not work.

```
                    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:MominDB","","");

                    stmt = con.createStatement();
                    rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(breakstart))) from Break ");
                    String s1=null;
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                    System.out.println(rs);

                     s1=rs.getString(1);

                    }
                    System.out.println(s1);
```

It is showing RUN Time error as Undefined function 'SEC_TO_TIME' in expression.

Comment: I'm confused as to exactly what you want. Are you saying you have a database with times in the format hh:mm:ss and you want to sum these times together and produce a final result in the same hh:mm:ss format?

Comment: Yes! That Exactly what I want

Comment: @eggyal, In my case I have three columns first is BreakStartTime which is in (hh:mm:ss) second column is BreakEndTime which is also in (hh:mm:ss) format Third column is TotalTime which is again in (hh:mm:ss) format. Now, I want to sum up each column and get the result in (hh:mm:ss) format. so that I can display it on a JLabel on my panel.

Comment: I am confused with your question, I am using Ms-Access as a database and fetching the values via Mysql Query in java.

Comment: *"I am confused with your question, I am using Ms-Access as a database and fetching the values via Mysql Query in java."* - I am confused by your comment. Is the data actually stored in MySQL or in an Access database file (.mdb or .accdb)? In other words, is "Break" a local table in the Access database file, or is it an ODBC Linked Table in Access that points to a table on a MySQL server?

Comment: @Gord Thompson , To be very simple, I have a Microsoft Access database file with extension (.mdb) and in that file I have a Table named as "Break". To insert records in this table I use mysql  query through a java program. as I have mentioned above in my code, I have edited my code with Connection syntax. Please refer that and help me please. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Be aware, the date/time values in Access are based on double. Thus, numerically, the sum is a double, actually a count of days.

In Access you can convert the value with CDate:

```
TotalTime = CDate(2.66203703703704E-4) 
' Result: 00:00:23
```

Using pure math:

```
TotalSeconds = 2.66203703703704E-4 * 24 * 60 * 60
' Result: 23
```

I don't do Java, so I can't tell how to convert in Java, but the numeric zero value of date/time in Access is `1899-12-30 00:00:00`

So remove your string handling - time is not text.

Finally, this has nothing to do with MySQL so you add confusing by calling it a MySQL query.

Answer (score 1):

Further to Gustav's answer, let's take a look at what we get from the JDBC-ODBC Bridge in Java. The code

```java
String sql = 
        "SELECT SUM(totalbreak) AS breaksum FROM Break";
try (
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql)) {
    rs.next();
    Object o = rs.getObject("breaksum");
    System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
}
```

returns

```
java.lang.Double
```

so the SUM() of a Date/Time field in Access will be returned as a Double by the ODBC driver.

As Gustav mentions, the internal representation of a Date/Time in Access is a Double value where the integer portion represents the date and the fractional portion represents the time. So, 2.66203703703704E-4 days * 86400 seconds/day = 23 seconds.

Once you have the total number of seconds (note that one second is the maximum resolution of a Date/Time field in Access) you could format that value as hh:nn:ss in your Java code. One way to do that would be to use Apache commons-lang, like this:

```java
String sql = 
        "SELECT SUM(totalbreak) AS breaksum FROM Break";
try (
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(sql)) {
    rs.next();
    Double breaksumSeconds = rs.getDouble("breaksum") * 86400;
    Long breaksumMillis = breaksumSeconds.longValue() * 1000;
    String s = org.apache.commons.lang.time.DurationFormatUtils.formatDurationHMS(breaksumMillis);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

which returns

```
0:00:23.000
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer was really very help full for me. However, I am getting negative values when the time changes after 12:00 A.M. I would be your FAN if you would please give me a solution to this as well. I tried changing the Data types but still no proper results. Run time error occurred.

Comment: I took a break at 11:30 P.M. And again I resumed at 12:15 A.M. It showed me a runtime error with negative calculation of time.

Comment: If the break spans midnight then the end time will be numerically less than the start time and you will have to add 1 day to compensate. In an Access query using Date/Time values the expression would be something like `tEnd - tStart + IIf(tEnd < tStart, 1, 0)`.